# What is the author trying to say about the Chinese remainder theorem?

Tags: number-theory

I started reading chapter four of "Elementary Number Theory" by Underwood Dudley and, on page 39, it says

> Theorem 2. The Chinese Remainder Theorem. The system of congruences
>   $$x\equiv a_i\pmod{m_i}, \qquad i=1,\,2,\dots,\,k$$
>   where $\gcd(m_i,m_j)=1$ if $j\neq i$, has a unique solution modulo $(m_1m_2\dots m_k)$.

What does "a solution modulo $(m_1m_2\dots m_k)$" mean ? Don't you have to specify specify what the solution is congruent to ?

I was expecting something like " a unique solution ***congruent to [something]*** modulo $(m_1m_2\dots m_k)$.

Comment: It does specify: the solution must be congruent to $a_i$ modulo $m_i$. (all $i$ simultaneously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right this is worded badly. The uniqueness bit goes with the "modulo $m_1m_2...m_k$".

So the solution solves $s \equiv a_i \quad mod\ m_i$ for every $i$ and if you have another solution $s'$, then 
$$
s \equiv s'\ mod\ m_1m_2...m_k
$$

Comment: That makes it a lot more clear! Thanks!